# Programmatically Illustrating an Expansion Permutation

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, loops, draw

Based on the discussion over [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499447/programmatically-illustrating-permutations), I drew this: [image]
With this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows.meta}

\tikzset{cross line/.style={>=Stealth,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt, preaction={>=Stealth, draw=white, shorten >=5pt, shorten
<=5pt, line width=1.6pt}}}
%\tikzstyle{bullet} = [draw, circle,fill=cyan!20, minimum height=2.5em, text centered]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/perms/.style={code={
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#1} {
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
      \node[draw,bullet,] (T\Y) at (\Y,5) {\ifnum\Y<10 0\fi\Y};
      \node[draw,bullet] (B\the\numexpr\X) at (\Y,-5) {\ifnum\Y<10 0\fi\Y};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  }
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#1} {
    \draw[->,>=Stealth,shorten <=-0.35pt] (T\Y.south) -> (B\Y.north);
    \draw[cross line] (T\Y.south) -> (B\Y.north);
  }
}},bullet/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,line width=.4pt,text=black,text width={width("33")},align=center},
  scale=0.5,transform shape]

\pic{perms={3,2,1}};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My question is: What's an elegant way to do the same thing with a permutation where *some* numbers are mapped *more than once*. If they're all mapped twice, it's fine you can just do:

```
\pic{perms={3,1,2}};
\pic{perms={2,3,1}};
```

[image]
But you can't map one twice, unless they're all mapped twice. For instance, this will show an error:

```
\pic{perms={3,1,2}};
\pic{perms={2, , }};
```

And you can't map something like 1 to 48 unless there are at least 48 numbers in the list.
Here's an example of an expansion permutation from Wikipedia:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

This problem is in a way simpler than the original one, at least if you know that there is an undocumented math function `dim` in `pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex`. This allows one to make it possible to add lists instead of single items for those cases in which one number should get mapped to multiple targets. `dim` can then be used to decide whether this is a single item or a list.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\tikzset{cross line/.style={>=Stealth,shorten >=5pt,shorten <=5pt, preaction={>=Stealth, draw=white, shorten >=5pt, shorten
<=5pt, line width=1.6pt}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/perms/.style={code={
  \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {#1}
  {\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\mydim}{dim(\X)}
  \node[draw,bullet] (T\Y) at (\Y,5) {\ifnum\Y<10 0\fi\Y};
  \ifnum\mydim=1
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
   \node[draw,bullet] (B\the\numexpr\X) at (\X,-5) {\ifnum\X<10 0\fi\X};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \draw[->,>=Stealth,shorten <=-0.35pt] (T\Y.south) -- (B\X.north);
   \draw[cross line] (T\Y.south) -- (B\X.north);
  \else
   \foreach \Z in \X
   {\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
   \node[draw,bullet] (B\the\numexpr\Z) at (\Z,-5) {\ifnum\Z<10 0\fi\Z};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \draw[->,>=Stealth,shorten <=-0.35pt] (T\Y.south) -- (B\Z.north);
   \draw[cross line] (T\Y.south) -- (B\Z.north);
   }
  \fi}
}},bullet/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,line width=.4pt,text=black,text width={width("33")},align=center},
  scale=0.5,transform shape]

\pic{perms={3,5,{1,4},{2,6}}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]